# How to add new sublibraries for pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to add a new "sub-library" (I do not know how to refer to these), called ExText for text input in the Pygame GUI.
http://pygame.org/project-EzText-920-.html

I am not sure how to add this sub library. I have tried placing the file in the Pygame folder, but that does not work. Could anyone please instruct me on how to add new sub-libraries for Pygame?

Comment: we call it `module`. You can add to `sys.path` full path to this module before you try to import. Or put EzText in folder with your project (not with Pygame) and maybe it will work without `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Put file `eztext.py` in folder with your script and then you can do `import eztext`.

Or add to `sys.path` path to folder with `eztext.py`

```
import sys

sys.path.append("path_to_folder")

import eztext
```